# Wait the call to database

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is there some method to wait until the call is completed? This is the code:

```
NSString *strImmagineURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.xxxgo.net/Scxxs/Evento/WIG2ricexxx.php?evento=%@",idLocale];
NSData *dataImmagineURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strImmagineURL]];
immagine = [UIImage imageWithData:dataImmagineURL];

 [`arrayFoto` addObject:immagine];
```

I noticed that, when the connection in slow, addObject crashes my app because `immagine` is still nil.

I want to wait for `immagine` and afterward fill `arrayFoto`.

Comment: I was pretty sure dataWithContentsOfURL was a blocking call. Are you sure its because the connection is slow and not because the url is sometimes returning a nil object?

Answer (score 1):

It's nil not because it's slow, but because the request *failed*. `dataWithContentsOfURL:` is a synchronous method, meaning execution of your program will not continue until the request completes or fails.

Properly handling error cases in HTTP requests requires a lot more setup. You should use something like [ASI HTTP Request](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) to handle your requests and success/error handlers more gracefully.